# Editing java files made by cordova to access GPS sensor in Android

Tags: java, android, cordova, gps

I am trying to build a mobile android app with jquery mobile and cordova. I have found that the native GPS sensor cannot be accesses directly by cordova application. Is it possible to edit the java files created by cordova ,so that the sensor can be accessed?

Comment: haven't used cordova but if HTML5 can access GPS of a phone then i'm sure cordova can. try geolocation "http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html"

Answer (score 1):

Cordova has inside a lot of native plugin that allow you to do a lot of things BUT is not only this. As you can see in DOC you can create your custom plugin to performe some native code (java) and return the result to JS.

For GPS you can search a plugin, I found this https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation, it should works.

In any case Cordova isn't magic, you must know java and android sdk to do all